# The meaning of this here?

Tags: c#, this

I'm a novice of programming who's learning C# recently.

When reading my textbook, I see the code below:

```
public class Panda
    {
        public Panda Mate;
            
        public void Marry(Panda partner)
        {
            Mate = partner;
            partner.Mate = this;
        }
    }
```

The book says that `this` here is used to set the `mate` field of `partner`, but I don't know what does that mean.

I'll be a big help if someone can explain it to me.

Comment: It's a reference to the current instance of `Panda`. If you access `partner.Mate`, that will be the same object as `this`

Answer (score 2):

`"this"` Panda gets married to the Partner supplied as parameter to the `Marry` method.
So, the `Mate` of the Partner is `this` Panda.

"this" Panda's Mate is the Partner. The Partner's Mate is this Panda.
They are connected vice-versa.

Technically, "this" in this case is a pointer to itself set as Mate on the Partner's Panda instance.